# error argument is of length zero in for loo

Tags: r, for-loop

I have created a vector of columns:

```
prv_services <- c("PRV_SERV_1", "PRV_SERV_2")
```

I want to sum up the total count each time a variable in the vector takes a value of "1", but I get an error argument is of length zero; what I expect is a summed total count for each observation in the data set. What is the solution to this?

```
data$prv_services = NA
for (val in c(1:nrow(data))) {
  the.sum = 0
  for (c in prv_services){
    if (!is.na(data[val, c]) & data[val,c] != "D" & data[val,c] != "R"){
      if (as.numeric(data[val,c]) == 1){
        the.sum = the.sum + 1
      }
    }
  }

}


Error in if (!is.na(data[val, c]) & data[val, c] != "D" & data[val, c] !=  : 
  argument is of length zero
```

This is the example data

```
#vector

Services <- c("prv_serv_1", "prv_serv_2")
Patient_ID <- c("A", "B" , "C")
Obs_1 <-c(0, 1)
Obs_2 <-c(1, 1)
Obs_3 <-c(1, 0)

#matrix

Services_Matrix <-rbind(Obs_1, Obs_2, Obs_3)
rm(Obs_1, Obs_2, Obs_3)
colnames(Services_Matrix) <- Services
rownames(Services_Matrix) <- Patient_ID
```

This is the new code with rowSums:

```
 df <- data.frame(prv_serv_1=c(0, 1, 1),
             prv_serv_2=c(1,1,0),
             prv_serv_3=c(0,0,1),
             prv_serv_4=c(0,1,0))
rowSums(df)
```

Comment: I would avoid using `c` as your iterative variable. `c` is a primitive function in R. Use `i` instead. Can you share a sample of your data using `dput`? I suspect there's a much easier way to do this.

Comment: Thank you! I've updated with the data, how would you use "i" instead?

Comment: `sapply(dat[,prv_services], function(z) sum(z == 1))`? or perhaps even shorter `colSums(dat[,prv_services] == 1)`?

Comment: Thanks so much! I tried the colSums and rowSums functions. I am now using the rowSums function to sum up the count of values across a row for specific columns in a dataset. Is there a way to select specific columns with rowSums?

Comment: There are ways to select specific columns _from a frame_ (and matrix) in general and then feed that data to `rowSums`. The function itself does not have any notion of column-selection.

Comment: Perhaps it would help to provide your expected output (as a frame, vector, matrix, or something), as a literal object.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you are trying to count the frequency of `1` in each column. Then it can be achieved with the following code.

```
colSums(df == 1)
```